# Column names missing when exporting files using SAS data step

Tags: csv, sas

I have a large SAS dataset `raw_data` which contains data collected from various countries. This dataset has a column "country" which lists the country from which the observation is originated. I would like to export a separate .csv file for each country in `raw_data`. I use the following data step to produce the output:

```
data _null_;
  set raw_data;
  length fv $ 200;
  fv = "/directory/" || strip(put(country,$32.)) || ".csv";
  file write filevar=fv dsd dlm=',';
  put (_all_) (:);
run;
```

However, the resulting .csv files no longer have the column names from `raw_data`. I have over a hundred columns in my dataset, so listing all of the column names is prohibitive. Can anyone provide me some guidance on how I can modify the above code so as to attach the column names to the .csv files being exported? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a macro variable that holds the variable names and puts them to the CSV file.

```
proc sql noprint;
select name into :var_list separated by ", "
from sashelp.vcolumn
where libname="WORK" and memname='RAW_DATA'
order by varnum;
quit;

data _null_;
set raw_data;
length fv $ 200;
by country;
fv = "/directory/" || strip(put(country,$32.)) || ".csv";

if first.country then do;
    put "&var_list";
end;

file write filevar=fv dsd dlm=',';
put (_all_) (:);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Reeza! In the proc sql statement you provided, do I need to list the names manually in the select clause? I have a few hundred columns so I would like to automate this as much as possible.

Comment: No...thats what the SQL statement does, it creates the list of names.

Comment: Hmm...when I run this, I get the following error: "ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: name."

Comment: Fixed it above, referenced wrong table - should be vcolumn. This is a table that holds all the metadata about your tables, the info that populates proc contents.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this data step that is very similar to your program.  It uses VNEXT to query the PDV and write the variable names as the first record of each file.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
   by age;
   run;
data _null_;
   set class;
   by age;
   filevar=catx('\','C:\Users\name\Documents',catx('.',age,'csv'));
   file dummy filevar=filevar ls=256 dsd;
   if first.age then link names;
   put (_all_)(:);
   return;
names:
   length _name_ $32;
   call missing(_name_);
   do while(1);
      call vnext(_name_);
     if _name_ eq: 'FIRST.' then leave;
      put _name_ @;
     end;
   put; 
   run;
```

Comment: Test for 'FIRST.' (include the period). Also move the FILEVAR= and FILE statements into the NAMES block. Otherwise the PUT _ALL_ will write the values of FILEVAR also.

Comment: Agree on the FIRST. but you need to test the program before you make comments you don't know the answer to.

Comment: Testing was the problem, but in testing I commented out the FILE statement so that I could see the values in the LOG.  That made the variable appear in the \_ALL_ list.